# How can I find the common station between two points of a map in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

There is the situation: I have little part of the London underground declared on specific lines in Prolog.  I have 3 lines with several stations, and they all have common points with each other.

[image: The map of the underground]

I have facts for the stations, where the arguments are the stations next to one another and the line what they are on. There is the full list of the stations on the map:

```
neighbour(south_kensington,victoria,green).
neighbour(victoria,westminster,green).
neighbour(westminster,embankment,green).
neighbour(embankment,blackfriars,green).
neighbour(vauxhall,victoria,blue).
neighbour(victoria,green_park,blue).
neighbour(green_park,oxford_circus,blue).
neighbour(oxford_circus,warren_street,blue).
neighbour(warren_street,euston,blue).
neighbour(warren_street,tottenham_court_road,black).
neighbour(tottenham_court_road,leichester_square,black).
neighbour(leichester_square,charing_cross,black).
neighbour(charing_cross,embankbent,black).
neighbour(embankment,waterloo,black).
```

The problem is: I want to go from A to B (they are on different lines) and Mr Prolog should say at which station I should change the lines. For example: A: Charing Cross; B: Westminster; Change at: Embankment

Comment: this sounds like a homework question, isn't it?

Comment: if you don't know where to start from, then is a good indicator that you should re-read your books, once you have a progress (i.e. a source code) you can ask a punctual question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement of the problem is not entirely clear. Are you looking for a route with one change only, or any number of changes is possible.

1) Consider travelling over your part of the Tube from Vauxhall to Waterloo. There is a route via Westminster with two changes and a route via Warren Street with only one change. Are both routes admissible or only one of them?

2) Correct a typo in the name of Embankment station in
    neighbour(charing_cross,embankbent,black).

3) Define a predicate station_on_line(St,Li) that holds if and only if a station St is on a line Li and check that for a query `station_on_line(St,blue)` it returns each station exactly once, and likewise `station_on_line(victoria,Li)` returns each line Victoria station is on only once.

4) Define a predicate `change_at(L1,L2,C)` that holds true if lines `L1` and `L2` meet at the station `C`.

5) Cases 3) and 4) will be enough to find a station to change if only one change is permissible, i.e. path from Vauxhall to Waterloo via Westminster is not admissible in 1).

6) Design a recursive definition that lets you find a path through an arbitrary number of stations on a network with an arbitrary number of lines.